# How can I truncate a string and remove a trailing character if present?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable:

```
a = "test data";
a = "test data!";
```

How can I remove the '!' if it exists at the end of the string? If possible I am looking for a method that would be the most clean solution.

Comment: Yes just if it was the last character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shortest way is to use [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with `!$`, which means *"match exclamation `!` mark right before the end `$` of the string"*:

```
'test data!'.replace(/!$/, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

if you didn't want to use a regular expression, you could use this logic.  The syntax below is in javascript, because I'm on a NodeJS kick these days, but you could tailor to any language.

```
function removeTrailExclamation(str) {
    return str.charAt(str.length-1) == '!' ? str.substring(0,str.length-1) : str;
}
```

If you're not comfortable with conditional operators

```
function removeTrailExclamation(str) {
    if(str.charAt(str.length-1) == '!') {
        return str.substring(0,str.length-1);
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to replace only at the end... using [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```
if(a.charAt(a.length - 1)=='!')
     a.substring(0, a.length - 1);
```

if every where..

```
a..replace(!, '');
```

Comment: But if the last character is not a ! then I don't want to remove it. I think in that case your first suggestion will not work. Is there a way to implement your first suggestion if it's shown that the last character is an exclamation mark?

Comment: It's not "every where". Just only if the last character is a !

Comment: fine it was a mistake...check if the last charac is a '!' then remove it,well..@VisioN's answer is the perfect one..